# Espresso: How to call evaluateJavascript() on a WebView

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am trying to get an instance of a `WebView`, so that I can call `evaluateJavascript()` on it.
I wrote a custom matcher and then tried to assign the `WebView` to a static variable as below:

```
 public static WebView view1;

 public static Matcher<View> isJavascriptEnabled1() {
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, WebView>(WebView.class) {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("WebView with JS enabled");
        }
        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(WebView webView) {
            view1 =webView;
            return webView.getSettings().getJavaScriptEnabled();
        }
    };
}
```

---

And in my test class I call:

```
 CustomMatcher.isJavascriptEnabled1();
 CustomMatcher.view1.evaluateJavascript("$('.status dl       dd').get(0).innerText.replace('pts.', '').replace(',', '').trim()\"]",new    ValueCallback<String>() {
   @Override
   public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
       Log.d("LogName", s); // Prints asd
   }
```

});

I get the error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String, android.webkit.ValueCallback)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 6):

You are not using the `Matcher` to match a view. It's not working because calling `isJavascriptEnabled1()` just creates a new instance of your custom `Matcher`. But e.g. `matchesSafely()` is never executed and thats why `CustomMatcher.view1` is `null`.
To make your code work you have to use `Espresso.onView()` together with your `Matcher`:

```
 // Use onView and the matcher to find a web view with enabled java script
 Espresso.onView(CustomMatcher.isJavascriptEnabled1());

 // Now CustomMatcher.view1 should not be null (if there is a web view)
 CustomMatcher.view1.evaluateJavascript("$('.status dl       dd').get(0).innerText.replace('pts.', '').replace(',', '').trim()\"]",new    ValueCallback<String>() {
   @Override
   public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
       Log.d("LogName", s); // Prints asd
   }
});
```

But thats still not correct. The method `evaluateJavascript()` is asynchronous and Espresso will not wait for the callback (`onReceiveValue()`) to be called. So the test will most likely finish before `onReceive()` is called.

There is also [Espresso Web](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/web/index.html) for testing `WebViews`. Depending on your goal you might find it useful. Espresso Web executes java script under the hood, too.

Without using Espresso Web I would suggest to write a custom `ViewAction`, that will be performed on the matched `WebView`. This action can use the `WebView` to evaluate java script:

```
/**
 * {@link ViewAction} that evaluates javascript in a {@link WebView}.
 */
public class EvaluateJsAction implements ViewAction, ValueCallback<String> {

    private static final long TIME_OUT = 5000;
    private final String mJsString;
    private final AtomicBoolean mEvaluateFinished = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public EvaluateJsAction(final String javaScriptString) {
        mJsString = javaScriptString;
    }

    @Override
    public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
        return isAssignableFrom(WebView.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "evaluate '" + mJsString + "' on webview";
    }

    @Override
    public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
        uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();

        final WebView webView = (WebView) view;
        webView.evaluateJavascript(mJsString, this);

        final long timeOut = System.currentTimeMillis() + TIME_OUT;
        while (!mEvaluateFinished.get()) {
            if (timeOut < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                throw new PerformException.Builder()
                        .withActionDescription(this.getDescription())
                        .withViewDescription(HumanReadables.describe(view))
                        .withCause(new RuntimeException(String.format(Locale.US,
                                "Evaluating java script did not finish after %d ms of waiting.", TIME_OUT)))
                        .build();
            }
            uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(50);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
        mEvaluateFinished.set(true);
    }
}
```

Then use this action:

```
onView(withJavaScriptEnabled()).perform(new EvaluateJsAction(theJavaScriptString));
```

Comment: Really appreciate your time to answer this question, really helpful.Thanks.